# Lip sync animation with rigify+pitchipoy armature and papagayo

Tags: animation, armature, bones, pose-mode

I would like to configure the lip sync and the eyes movements on my character rigged with the rigify/pitchipoy armature and papagayo. I don't like the shape keys. I prefer to use bones and pose library. So,I found this script :

[lip sync script](https://morevnaproject.org/2015/11/11/automatic-lipsync-animation-in-blender/)

and I tried to follow this short tutorial :

[short tutorial](https://vimeo.com/144069038)

Now,the problem is that it is too short and some important parts are missing ? Infact it starts with the pose library full of phoenemes,but I don't know how to add them into the library. Or better,generally I know how to add a pose,but in this specific case,I don't know which kind of phoenemes are those and how to create them. I have exported the dat file from my audio file and this is the content :

[image]

but now,starting from these phoenemes,what should I do ? Should I create a pose for each phoenemes moving the mouth bones ? But in which ways ? Does the script make the pose automatically based on the phonemes that it finds in the dat file ?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at post of lipsync script that you referenced - https://morevnaproject.org/2015/11/11/automatic-lipsync-animation-in-blender/. It says:

> use a Pose Library to define a mouth poses for the face rig of your
>   model. Each pose should be named as corresponding phoneme in your
>   lipsync breakdown – “MBP”, “AA”, “O”, “EHSZ”, “etc”… (just inspect the
>   .dat file produced by Papagayo to figure out which phonemes you need).

So, just open your .dat file and see which phonemes it uses. Then open your model file and create Poses for your Pose library. Each pose should be named in the same way as phoneme. I.e. for “O” phoneme you need to set bones of your character’s lips in the same way as he says “o”. Then save this pose into the Pose Library under the name “O”. I hope that helps.

P.S. The lipsync script works with any armature. The link referenced in your other answer points to different script.

Comment: If I use the MHX2 framework I don't need shape-keys and/or the pose library. Instead,If I use the rigify script I need to create one pose for each phoneme defined into the dat file. I did it and it worked. My doubt was that in the short video of Terry Hancock I don't understand which kind of armature he used. The video is too short. It starts with the poses already created. Instead,for a better understanding,it was better to explain that with rigify it needs to create the mouth poses,but it is not necessary if you use the makehuman armature...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. Read here :

https://tentacles.org.uk/quicktalk

where he says :

The script has now been update to allow using MHX2 imported models created by Makehuman. If the Makehuman characters have been exported from Makehuman and imported into Blender with Thomas MakeHuman’s Script and you pick “MHX2” as the format (rather than X-Rotation or X-Translation) then there’s no need to even make shape-keys or build bone-panels.

This is what I needed to know,because since I'm using rigify+pitchipoi armature,that from some point of view it's better than the makehuman armature,from the point of view of a correct configuration of the lip synching is less powerful than it,infact if I use it,I need to make shape keys and/or bone-panels. And Terry Hancock on this tutorial :

https://vimeo.com/144069038

forgot to say that he using a character made with makehuman and that he has installed the MHX2 framework and that have the advantages over the rigify armature as I have explained before. And most important,that making so short tutorials is not good nor for beginners because they confuses them, nor for the blender gurus, because they don't need them.